# How retrieve data from a 2D array on this particular case?

Tags: php

I have a array with this var_dump value:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$table` WHERE my mysql conditions");
```

**var_dump($query); is this:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#414 (1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(3) "494" } }
```

How can I get the number 494 inside a variable?

$number = $query[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be cleaner if you aliased your count so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
```

then

```
$number = $query[0]->count;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to retrieve a single value, use [`$wpdb->get_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) instead of `get_results()`. This method exists specifically for situations like yours.

```
$number = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$table` WHERE my mysql conditions");
```